# I want to increase the number of vertices in a cylinder

Tags: modeling, vertices

I want to increase the number of vertices in a cylinder I have a version of 2.90 in blender.
Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Suggestion.  Show your work as a Blender Screen Capture.  Delete your current cylinder and create a new one with more vertices from the very start. ... Or ... Search and see video tutorials on Adding Cylinders, Loop Cut and Subdivision Surface Modifier.  You stated in the original title you are new to Blender .. therefore videos will serve you well.

Comment: Add a  screen and draw vertices in place you want to increase. From Q its not clear where you need them - side, top/bottom ...

Answer (score 1):

When doing most actions in 2.8+, and in the case of adding an object <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> there will be a menu popup, by default in the lower left portion of the screen, edit the top box, labelled vertices, to your preference.

[image]

Alternatively, in edit mode, select the top and bottom loops with alt, then use the vertex context menu by right clicking, and select subdivide on the loops.

Or with cursor in middle of cylinder press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> move a bit with cursor until first yellow ring appears, then you can add more loops by scroll wheel or pressing number.  Enter.

[image]

Or if you just need to make cylinder look smooth, you dont have to add vertices - change shading to Smooth and in Properties Editor, Mesh Data, Normals, **Auto Smooth**.

Comment: Thanks for your help buddy! But i have a version 2.90 and there is no pop-up menu i can see.Is there anyway to enable this pop-menu i think it's disable maybe.!!1

Comment: Hey now I understand how to add more vertices.There was a pop-up menu as you said,but in mine it was closed down there was an arrow by pressing them There was a pop-up menu came just like your's.BTW,thanks for ur help

Comment: you can also use **F9** to bring up a floating window with the same controls.